How to return my random ids as each value in a list and not an object
I have a json file that contains individual events and their markets like so:
   {
  "eventId": "317a66b5-3da3-4ab3-9273-434441d87f20",
  "markets": [
    [
      {
        "id": "38193a94-036b-41a2-a874-fe63ca8aaff4"
      },
      {
        "id": "1790671e-81c5-4ff4-885a-1f8eee0b0e6b"
      },
      {
        "id": "e37551d3-9e95-4701-8515-df88f4bb2180"
      },
      {
        "id": "03d8fea1-90f9-4b76-84dd-44e5ed072bd0"
      },
      {
        "id": "91ef3269-0c88-428f-819a-c0fd56a630e3"
      },
      {
        "id": "fdfc525a-a4ea-4956-b81b-ede2d8722a0b"
      },
      {
        "id": "e9d978e8-45d4-421c-b75e-57bd1907fa9f"
      },
      {
        "id": "ab344bbc-1f8e-4758-b86d-7615affe1295"
      },
      {
        "id": "00e32dc7-73c8-44dd-8f7f-f988d7f42992"
      }
    ]
  ]
},
{
  "eventId": "93a9e201-2d33-4358-89e6-f7d140b09a2e",
  "markets": [
    [
      {
        "id": "aac79642-f11d-4f4b-8048-6ac96843ccf1"
      },
      {
        "id": "8981b626-7357-4e6f-a998-d1e36515261a"
      },
      {
        "id": "045c235a-1fb8-4a9f-b2c5-13da379b6ad8"
      },
      {
        "id": "786c86ad-f465-4f6c-b5a3-4114a54a05b6"
      },
      {
        "id": "86618747-94df-43e4-a8a4-8613419f7217"
      },
      {
        "id": "845b9235-242f-4e0c-827e-4cdfce6ed71d"
      },
      {
        "id": "20ad2669-73e2-4d56-a9b6-8834efa8d95a"
      },
      {
        "id": "5805d0ba-f407-48e7-be52-af2892ccb355"
      },
      {
        "id": "66065767-c46c-4656-9ff9-c81f30704896"
      }
    ]
  ]
},
...

I have included a piece of code where I want to randomly select an event and output it's event id and all its markets:
 const randomIndex = Math.floor(
        Math.random() * data.length
      );
    let eventId = data[randomIndex].eventId;
    let marketIds = data[randomIndex].markets;

However, I notice for the marketIds variable, it outputs each market id like this:
[
      {
        "id": "38193a94-036b-41a2-a874-fe63ca8aaff4"
      },
      {
        "id": "1790671e-81c5-4ff4-885a-1f8eee0b0e6b"
      },
      {
        "id": "e37551d3-9e95-4701-8515-df88f4bb2180"
      },
      {
        "id": "03d8fea1-90f9-4b76-84dd-44e5ed072bd0"
      },
      {
        "id": "91ef3269-0c88-428f-819a-c0fd56a630e3"
      },
      {
        "id": "fdfc525a-a4ea-4956-b81b-ede2d8722a0b"
      },
      {
        "id": "e9d978e8-45d4-421c-b75e-57bd1907fa9f"
      },
      {
        "id": "ab344bbc-1f8e-4758-b86d-7615affe1295"
      },
      {
        "id": "00e32dc7-73c8-44dd-8f7f-f988d7f42992"
      }
    ]

I was hoping the marketIds will be returned like this (without the curly braces):
[
        "38193a94-036b-41a2-a874-fe63ca8aaff4",
        "1790671e-81c5-4ff4-885a-1f8eee0b0e6b",
        "e37551d3-9e95-4701-8515-df88f4bb2180",
        "03d8fea1-90f9-4b76-84dd-44e5ed072bd0",
        "91ef3269-0c88-428f-819a-c0fd56a630e3",
        "fdfc525a-a4ea-4956-b81b-ede2d8722a0b",
        "e9d978e8-45d4-421c-b75e-57bd1907fa9f",
        "ab344bbc-1f8e-4758-b86d-7615affe1295",
        "00e32dc7-73c8-44dd-8f7f-f988d7f42992"
    ]

How can I get the data to be returned as a list of values?

I notice for the marketIds variable, it outputs each market id like this: well, that's what data[randomIndex].markets is, if you want a different format, you need to manipulate the data. - use Array map method - in your previous question about this you commented ah I need to read up about maps ... but it' not maps, it's Array.prototype.map you need to "read up" about

You're close, you just need to use .map() to extract the IDs and return a new array.
const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length);
let eventId = data[randomIndex].eventId;
let marketIds = data[randomIndex].markets[0].map(market => market.id);


Hey, I did actually try this above map method before, but it returns null when I attempted this.  console.log('MARKETS', marketIds) returns me MARKETS [null] 

Oh figured it, it's within an array so it's like this: let marketIds = data[randomIndex].markets[0].map(market => market.id); Thank you for that

marketIds[0].map(marketId => marketId.id)

More on maps
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
